# Need to blend a scatterplot with a radar chart for plotting golf shots - possible in D3? Example image included

Tags: d3.js

I'd like to plot golf shots as dots on a pie-shaped radar chart, given their distance traveled and distance off center. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVhXv.jpg

I've got quite a bit of experience with D3, and have explored most of what D3 offers off-the-shelf, but this looks like it will be more complicated. I appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks!

The csv data will look like:

```
distance,offline
161,1.2
159,-3.5
164,-1.9
163,6.1
etc
```

Comment: looks fairly straight forward honestly, though with maybe some vector or trig math involved.

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. You may want to edit the question and make it more precise. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).